# How to get gridview row value while rowdeleting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to delete the row of gridview. So i added Commandfield Delete button for all rows. When i click to delete button, it triggers `gvBooklist_RowDeleting` event. In that i'm giving the following code to get current book name.

```
string tempBook = gvBooklist.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].ToString();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select id from tBooks where bookName = '" + tempBook + "';");
```

But tempBook returns `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell`. How do i get the actual book name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) use it's [`Text` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell.text(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string tempBook = gvBooklist.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
```

Side note: you also should use sql-parameters - always:

```
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("Select id from tBooks where bookName = @bookname"))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@bookname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tempBook;
    // ...
}
```